# How to squash records in a table using a single query?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a following table in **postgres**:

```
CREATE TABLE "post_version" (
  "id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "post_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "version" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "content" JSONB NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),

  UNIQUE INDEX "post_version.post_id_version_unique" ("post_id", "version"),
  CONSTRAINT "post_version_post_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("post_id") REFERENCES "public"."post" ("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

For a given `post_id` it maintains the multiple copies of a post. The column `version` is incremented by one each time new content is saved for a post (version begins from 1 and is always incremental). I want to provide an API to delete all the previous drafts and reset the version back to **one**.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_version WHERE post_id = 1;

-- The $count is the count received in previous query
DELETE FROM post_version WHERE VERSION < $count;

UPDATE post_version SET VERSION = 0 WHERE post_id = 1;
```

Currently, all the three queries run within a transaction. Is there a way to achieve the same with some sort of `update`, `merge` or `upsert` query so that I can do the same without explicit transaction? The reason I need to do this is I am using **prisma** which doesn't currently support transactions!

Comment: You have a primary key on id and a unique constraint on id, version? That doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Also I would recommend MAX(version) over count(*). Max is guaranteed to be right. Count isn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in a single statement.  However, you can simplify your code a bit:

```
DELETE FROM post_version pv
    WHERE pv.VERSION < (SELECT MAX(version)
                        FROM post_version pv2
                        WHERE pv2.post_id = pv.post_id
                       ) AND
          pv.post_id = 1;

UPDATE post_version SET VERSION = 1 WHERE post_id = 1;
```

Note that this also explicitly keeps the maximum version rather than assuming that the count is the maximum.  It also fixes the bug in your code where you set the version to `0` rather than `1`.

You could also using a single statement with a data-modifying CTE.  The logic would be something like:

```
WITH max_version AS (
      SELECT post_id, MAX(version) as max_version
      FROM post_version pv
      WHERE post_id = 1
      GROUP BY post_id
     ),
     d AS (
      DELETE FROM post_version pv
      WHERE pv.VERSION < (SELECT mv.max_version
                          FROM max_version mv
                          WHERE mv.post_id = pv.post_id
                         ) 
     )
UPDATE post_version pv
   SET version = 1
   WHERE pv.VERSION < (SELECT mv.max_version
                       FROM max_version mv
                       WHERE mv.post_id = pv.post_id
                      ) ;

UPDATE post_version SET VERSION = 1 WHERE post_id = 1;
```

You have to be careful because the the `post_version` doesn't change *within* the statement, so the `UPDATE` sees the "deleted" rows.  They are deleted when the transaction completes.